# Remove known password from directory of Excel files with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, passwords

I have found this VBA code and it works to remove the known password on one Excel workbook just fine.

```
Sub testPasswordRemoval()

Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Temp\Book2.xlsm", Password:="pw")
wb.Password = ""
wb.SaveAs "C:\Temp\NewBook.xlsm"

End Sub
```

But, I have tried various tutorials and videos (many folks offering this) but none of them work to loop through a folder of .xlsx files (all with the same known password) and remove that same password.

I am not a VBA person, but have spent about 16 hours over the past three days trying to crack the code on this one.  I have found several examples of looping over files in a directory, but none that enabled me to put the above code into them and loop and remove passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, read the comments, and adjust it to fit your needs

**Code:**

```
Public Sub RemovePassLoopThroughFiles()
    
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim folderWildcard As String
    Dim currentFileName As String
    Dim currentFileExtension As String
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim newfileNameSuffix As String
    Dim currentPassword As String
    Dim newPassword As String
    
    ' Adjust next lines to fit your needs
    
    folderPath = "C:\Temp\" ' With slash at the end
    folderWildcard = "*.xls*" ' You can change the suffix to open specific files
    
    newfileNameSuffix = "_NoPassword"
    
    currentPassword = "pw"
    newPassword = ""
    
    ' Get the file path concat folder and wildcards
    filePath = Dir(folderPath & folderWildcard)
      
    
    Do While Len(filePath) > 0
        ' Open the workbook and set reference
        Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, Password:=currentPassword)
        
        ' Get current file extension
        currentFileExtension = Right(filePath, Len(filePath) - InStrRev(filePath, "."))
        
        ' Get filename no extension
        currentFileName = Left(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, ".") - 1)
        
        ' Build new fileName
        newFileName = currentFileName & newfileNameSuffix & "." & currentFileExtension
        
        ' Set new password
        targetWorkbook.Password = newPassword
        
        ' Save new file
        targetWorkbook.SaveAs folderPath & newFileName

        'Debug.Print filePath
        
        filePath = Dir

        targetWorkbook.Close True
        
        Set targetWorkbook = Nothing
        
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I will get on this right away and report back.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Shoot.  Got an error dialog box that I have seen before.  “Run-time error ‘1004’   “Sorry we couldn’t find [name of file name that is in the folder].  Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?”  So the code gets to the correct folder and then sees one of the files (I have three password protected workbooks in there to test) but then cannot find the file?  Strange since it correctly displays the file name but then errors on not being able to find it.  Ideas @ricardo?

Comment: I tinkered with your code and got it to remove passwords one after another .  I edited this line “ Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, Password:=currentPassword)”. To this, Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & “\” & folderWildcard, Password:=currentPassword).  But, now, all the files stay open after the password is removed and my memory gets used up.  How do I close each workbook after the new file is saved without a password?

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. Running that now and it appears to be working, closing the file after the password is removed.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting bug developed.  Now along with removing password, this code is copying the data from the first workbook to all subsequent workbooks.  Any idea how that might be happening?

Comment: I see. What data is it copying? all sheets? just one?

Comment: The code is copying the contents of the first sheet to all the other sheets.  Now, for some files, it is erasing all sheets such that no data remains.  Something is amiss.  I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code above and tried to run it.  It consistently throws an error on this line 'Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, Password:=currentPassword)'. No useful message from VBA as to why it is happening.

Comment: I just updated the code I am running right at this moment and bolded the line where it is failing.  The error dialog box contains the name of a file in the targeted folder and indicates that it cannot find that file "perhaps it has been moved or deleted?"  The file is in the folder, I can see it.  The code cannot see it.

Comment: So, solved the error noted in the comment above by changing this one line, 'Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, Password:=currentPassword) - TO THIS - 
        Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & folderWildcard, Password:=currentPassword), however, that again results in every workbook in the folder having their contents erased and replaced with the content from the first workbook which the code operates on.  So, either the script is failing or it is partially working but deleting all content in every other workbook and replacing it with the same content.

Comment: I suggest that you post a new question with the complete code. If you want, drop me a message here and I'll look into it. I can't see the edited code correctly.